# Importing data into R, when data isn't formatted as a table

Tags: r, dataframe, read.table

I have the following tabulator separated .txt file with 9796 lines:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/fnrbmaw8odm2rqs/Kommunale_N%C3%B8gletal.txt?dl=0

I would like to read the file into R, however the file is not in a classic table format. Instead, each variable of interest has 279 rows and 16 columns, where the first row defines the variable name, the first 2 columns define a municipality name and code, and the following 14 define the years from 1993-2006. Each variable is separated by a blank row. The file includes 35 variables.

I would like to read the data into a `data.frame`, but with one column for the municipality name, the municipality code, and the year, and one column for each of the 35 variables.

In case your are not comfortable following links or prefer a smaller sample, the following illustrates the dataset (2 variables and 3 years of observations):

```
Indbyggertal 1 januar
Københavns Kommune     101    466129    467253  471300
Frederiksberg Kommune  147    87173     87466   88002
Ballerup Kommune       151    45427     45293   45356

Andel 0-17-årige
Københavns Kommune     101    14.0      14.1    14.4
Frederiksberg Kommune  147    12.4      12.5    12.6
Ballerup Kommune       151    21.2      21.1    21.3
```

The first 3 lines of the preferred out should look like this:

```
Municipality name      Municipality code    Year    Indbyggertal 1 januar   Andel 0-17-årige    …   Ældreudg (netto) pr 65+/67+-årig
Københavns Kommune     101                  1993    466129                  14                      35350
Frederiksberg Kommune  147                  1993    87173                   12.4                    33701
Ballerup Kommune       151                  1993    45427                   21.2                    31126
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried? And how your output should look like?

Comment: I have just tried using `read.table` with different settings, but I think I need to either use some sort of `apply` or a `for` loop. I will try illustrating the preferred output.

Comment: you should include a sample of your data

Comment: @stasg I have included all my data in the link. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @Mace many people, including myself, are reluctant to follow third party dropbox links and download anything. your question should be self sufficient

Comment: @stasg: Okay, I will try to provide a illustrative sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably more ways for doing this, but the trick I used below is to read all data in as text, then determine the positions where new blocks begin, and finally loop through all blocks reading them in and storing them in a `list`:

```
lines <- readLines("Kommunale_Nøgletal.txt", encoding = "latin1")

# Find empty lines; these start a new block
start <- c(0, grep("^[\t]+$", lines))

# Read titles
headers <- lines[start + 1]
headers <- gsub("\t", "", headers)

# Determine beginnen and ending of data blocks
begin <- start + 2
end   <- c(start[-1]-1, length(lines))

# Read each of the data blocks into a list
data <- vector(mode = "list", length(headers))
for (i in seq_along(headers)) {
  block <- lines[begin[i]:end[i]]
  data[[i]] <- read.table(textConnection(block), sep="\t", na.strings=c("U","M","-"))
}
names(data) <- headers
```

Setting the correct headers in each of the data sets should be simple after this and combining then into one data.frame can be done using `rbind_all` from the `dplyr` package. Below an example:

```
# Set columnnames in data
# Add variable name to data
for (i in names(data)) {
  names(data[[i]]) <- c("municipality", "code", paste0("Y", 1993:2006))
  data[[i]]$var = i
}

# Merge the different datasets into one data.frame
library(dplyr)
data <- rbind_all(data)

# Transpose the data
library(reshape2)
m <- melt(data, id.vars = c("municipality", "code", "var"))
res <- dcast(m, municipality + code + variable ~ var)

# Fix the year variable
names(res)[3] <- "year"
res$year <- as.numeric(gsub("Y", "", res$year))
```

Comment: Thanks, looks good, but when I try running your code, it fails in the first line, saying incomplete final line. Can you get it to work?

Comment: That's just a warning I guess !!

Comment: @dikesh is right: you can generally ignore this warning. It just means what it says: the last line in the file doesn't end with a newline (enter). Sometimes this can indicate that a wrong encoding is used when reading the file.

Comment: Ah yeah - of course. I got it to work, and I now trying to convert the list into a `dataframe`. I will have a look at the `rbind_all` function from `dplyr`.

Comment: @JanvanderLaan: I have tried using `rbind_all`, but I can't see how I can transpose blocks so that the last 16 variables of each blocks are turned into rows (one for each of the 16 years from 1993 to 2006), and each block constitute a variable in the `data.frame`. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: @Mace Added an example to the answer